# variable depth persistence and relationships of type Set

Tags: neo4j, persistence, relationship, neo4j-ogm

I have the following relationships

Diagram -has-many- Connection
Connection -has-many MoveablePoints

I am using a neo4j omg repository interface v3.1.3 of neo4j to persist addition and removal of connections and moveable points. My unit tests are working fine, however if I use it in a web environment, the removal of the connections is not being applied.

I am using a variable depth persistence of 5. I feel this has something to do with the omg session but I am not sure. Any ideas would be welcome.

service code

```
@Transactional
    @Override
    @Retryable(value = TransientException.class,exceptionExpression="#{message.contains('RWLock')}", maxAttempts = 5)
    public Diagram update(Diagram diagram) throws GUMLException {

//        for (Connection connection : diagram.getConnections())
//            if (connection.getId() != null)
//                connectionService.deleteMoveablePoints(connection.getId());
//
//        for (DiagramElement de : diagram.getDiagramElements()) {
//            diagramElementService.save(de);
//        }


        return umlDiagramRepository.save(diagram, 5);

    }
```

domain classes

```
@NodeEntity
public class Diagram {
   public Set<Connection> getConnections() {
        if (connections == null)
            connections = new HashSet<Connection>();
        return connections;
    }

    public void setConnections(Set<Connection> connections) {
        this.connections = connections;
    }

    @org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Relationship(type = "HasConnections", direction = org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Relationship.OUTGOING)
    Set<Connection> connections;

}

@NodeEntity
public class Connection implements IConnector {
  public Set<MoveablePoint> getMoveablePoints() {
        return moveablePoints;
    }

    public void setMoveablePoints(Set<MoveablePoint> moveablePoints) {
        this.moveablePoints = moveablePoints;
    }


    @org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Relationship(type = "HasMoveablePoints", direction = org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Set<MoveablePoint> moveablePoints;

}
```

When I change my service code to retrieve the object from the session first and then overwrite, it seems to work. This does not seem right to me though.

```
Diagram d2 = umlDiagramRepository.findById(diagram.getId()).get();
        d2 = diagram;

        return umlDiagramRepository.save(d2, 5);
```

Comment: Can you see the right statements getting generated from the log output (debug level)?

Comment: Thanks for responding meistermeier. Yes I can see the correct cypher statement that should be being persisted. I've also added an event listener and log statements to pre a post save printing out the object being saved and it also reflects what should be happening. Still not working though..